# How do I program the output of one function to feed into the input of another?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, switch-statement, expression

If I have a function like this:

```
var danger = 1;

function stepLeft() {
    if (danger == 1) {
        alert("stop")
    } else {
        alert("start")
    }
 }
```

...how do I make the "alert("stop")" or any other output like that trigger and supply the expression input for something like a switch statement? So I can set off a chain reaction of consequences? Thanks!

Comment: I believe you're looking for a *prompt*? - https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/window.prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing concerns here.  An `alert()` is a UI action, it doesn't trigger anything in your code.  It just does something on the UI.  If you want your function to trigger something else in your code, you'd need to invoke that other thing:

```
function stepLeft() {
    if (danger == 1) {
        alert("stop")
        someOtherFunction();
    } else {
        alert("start")
        yetAnotherFunction();
    }
}
```

Or, if the functionality can change, you can supply a function to `stepLeft`:

```
function stepLeft(stopFunction, startFunction) {
    if (danger == 1) {
        alert("stop")
        stopFunction();
    } else {
        alert("start")
        startFunction();
    }
}
```

and call it:

```
stepLeft(someOtherFunction, yetAnotherFunction);
```

Or you might have `stepLeft` return a value, which other functions can use:

```
function stepLeft() {
    if (danger == 1) {
        alert("stop")
        return "stop";
    } else {
        alert("start")
        return "start";
    }
}
```

and call it:

```
var actionPerformed = stepLeft();
someOtherFunction(actionPerformed);
```

This would actually be a good opportunity to de-couple your UI actions from your logic:

```
function stepLeft() {
    if (danger == 1) {
        return "stop";
    } else {
        return "start";
    }
}
```

and:

```
var actionPerformed = stepLeft();
alert(actionPerformed);
someOtherFunction(actionPerformed);
```

The point is, there are a lot of ways to structure your code so that the results of one function can be used by another function.

Comment: I don't think this is what he meant... The question says *feed into the input of another*. I believe he wants a *prompt*

Comment: @LcSalazar: Possibly, though in that case it's very ambiguously described.  I wouldn't call a prompt the "output of a function".

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot! And I meant using "alert()" or any other output as a trigger. Don't know why this got -2 points, how am I suppose to know what I want to do without answering my own question? This site really isn't beginner friendly. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: @MarkusHallcyon: Don't take down-votes personally :)  If I were to guess, the community may have down-voted because the terminology used in the question is unclear or ambiguous, and it's difficult to discern exactly what you're trying to do.  To be honest, I kind of guessed at what you were asking.  But I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: The nature of asking questions is ambiguity.

Comment: @MarkusHallcyon: I disagree.  The nature of asking questions is to find answers.  As with any communication between two or more people, each party is responsible for communicating clearly and effectively.  This may prove rather difficult for the asker, particularly if he is unfamiliar with the terminology of the subject matter (as in this case).  But the nature of asking questions isn't a lack of clarity, it's a lack of information.  Arriving at meaningful information requires clarity as a prerequisite.

Comment: Semantical Confusion: *A nature of asking questions is ambiguity. Quite obviously that isn't the only purpose.